# How to sort an array of timestamps using lodash in desc order

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to sort the following array of timestamps using **lodash** so the latest time stamp is first [3].

Code:

```
let timestamps = ["2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z", "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z", "2017-04-24T00:41:18.000Z", "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z", "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z"]

const sorted = _.sortBy(timestamps);
```

This does not work as i expect, i believe its sorting them but in asc order.

Comment: `["2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z",
  "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z",
  "2017-04-24T00:41:18.000Z",
  "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z",
  "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z"
].sort()` - no need for lodash

Comment: do you have an array with the given iso dates or do you have an array of objects with timestamp properties?

Comment: @mplungjan this does the same in asc not desc. I need it from highest to lowest

Comment: @Kay, I think you are looking for [`_.orderBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#orderBy) instead of `_.sortBy()`

Comment: @Kay then make it `arr.sort( (a, b) => b > a ? 1 : -1 )`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to sort an array of timestamps using lodash

This code is already sorting timestamps correctly using lodash:

```
const sorted = _.sortBy(timestamps);
```

just in ascending order, simply reverse the result using:

```
const sorted = _.sortBy(timestamps).reverse();
```

Answer (score 9):

[orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy) allows you to specify the sort orders while sortBy does not.

```
const sorted = orderBy(timestamps, ['desc']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use Array.prototype.sort instead of lodash.
Kudos to **@mplungjan** and **@gurvinder372** for pointing out that `new Date` is useless.

Keep in mind that Array.prototype.sort updates the array on the place.

```js
const dates = [
      "2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z",
      "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z",
      "2017-04-24T00:41:18.000Z",
      "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z",
      "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z"
    ]

dates.sort((d1, d2) => d2 > d1 ? 1 : -1) // desc

console.log(dates)

dates.sort() // asc

console.log(dates)
```

Comment: Why create dates? They are in date order when string sorted

Comment: @havenchyk perfectly doable `arr.sort( (a, b) => b > a ? 1 : -1 )`

Comment: No need for a sort function either

Comment: for desc it's needed :)

Comment: Nope https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse - se my answer for example

Comment: @mplungjan but you need to modify an array twice then

Comment: But using built-in methods instead of compare functions - a JSPerf could tell us what is the fastest - ah - exists. https://jsperf.com/array-sort-reverse-vs-string-comparison - seems string comparison is 1.2% faster - not much when we only have 5 strings

Answer (score 1):

You could treat [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date strings as normal strings, because they are sortable as string.

```js
var array = ["2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z", "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z", "2017-04-24T00:41:18.000Z", "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z", "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z"];

array.sort((a, b) => b > a || -(b < a));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: No need for a sort function either.  .sort().reverse() will work just fine - I posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

The strings are sortable using built-in sorting - no need for lodash or a sort function

According to https://jsperf.com/array-sort-reverse-vs-string-comparison this is 1.2% slower than a string comparison - unimportant if few dates

[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```js
console.log(
["2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z", "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z", "2017-04-24T00:41:18.000Z", "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z", "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z" ]
 .sort()
 .reverse()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = ["2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z", "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z", "2017-04- 
24T00:41:18.000Z", "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z", "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z"];

_.sortBy(users, String);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be possible with these options

```
let timestamps = ["2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z", "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z", "2017-04-24T00:41:18.000Z", "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z", "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z"]

const sorterFunc = item => ((new Date()).getTime() - (new Date(item)).getTime());
const sorted = _.sortBy(timestamps, [sorterFunc]);
```

those will sort the array without having to call a method `.reverse()` at all.