# How to sort object per date field using lodash?

Tags: sorting, date, datetime, dictionary, lodash

I have this JavaScript object:

```
var items = [
  {
    name: "order 2",
    date: "2020-02-01T13:50:04.869Z",
  },  
  {
    name: "order 3",
    date: "2020-03-01T13:50:04.869Z",
  },  
  {
    name: "order 1",
    date: "2020-01-01T13:50:04.869Z",
  },
];
```

And I want to get the array `["order 1", "order 2", "order 3"]` where the names are taken and are ordered by date.

What I tried so far is (using `lodash`):

```
var array = _.map(
    _.sortBy(items, function(el) { return el.date; }), 
     function(el) { return el.name; }
);
```

Which is sorting the items, but my date is recognized as `string` and not as `date time`.

How do I sort this per date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of timestamps using lodash in desc order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673861/how-to-sort-an-array-of-timestamps-using-lodash-in-desc-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the `date` in the `_.sortBy()` iteratee function, and set the iteratee of `_.map()` to `name`:

```js
var items = [{"name":"order 2","date":"2020-02-01T13:50:04.869Z"},{"name":"order 3","date":"2020-03-01T13:50:04.869Z"},{"name":"order 1","date":"2020-01-01T13:50:04.869Z"}];

var array = _.map(
  _.sortBy(items, o => Date.parse(o.date)),
  'name'
);

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with that:

```js
var items  = [
  {
    name: "order 2",
    date: "2020-02-01T13:50:04.869Z",
  },  
  {
    name: "order 3",
    date: "2020-03-01T13:50:04.869Z",
  },  
  {
    name: "order 1",
    date: "2020-01-01T13:50:04.869Z",
  },
];

var names = items .sort(function compare(a, b) {
  var dateA = new Date(a.date);
  var dateB = new Date(b.date);
  return dateA - dateB;
}).map(v => v.name);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: Hello! Please consider adding an explanation of how your code works, to guide others.