# Cannot order the date by desc on Lodash

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, lodash

I get the data like so:

```
 getLeads(): Observable<LeadModel[]> {
    return this.angularFireDatabase
      .list<LeadModel>(`groups/${this.groupId}/leads`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(map((res) => orderBy(res, ['createdDate'], ['desc'])));
  }
```

.HTML

```
       <ion-col>
          <p>
            {{ lead.createdDate | date: 'MMM dd' }}
            <br />
            {{ lead.createdDate | date: 'h:mm a' }}
          </p>
        </ion-col>
```

I use [Lodash orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) here.

I use [DayJS](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) for date formating like so when I saved the data to Firebase

```
 createdDate: dayjs().format(),
```

But I cannot see the `date` order by `desc` here. Do you know why?

[image]

Comment: it is sorted, check the screenshot you posted

Comment: @AhmadAbuSaa Why then `16` is in between `15`?

Comment: sorry, you are right

Comment: i think you need to check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965727/sort-array-of-objects-with-date-field-by-date and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754781/how-to-sort-object-per-date-field-using-lodash because seems you are sorting strings instead of date objects

Comment: @AhmadAbuSaa You can see here where `Lodash` can detect `ISO8601` string as date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039241/1077309

Comment: Just cause a random comment say so does not mean it's true. Your source should be the documentation itself. I do not see this on the official documentation where order by detect string as date.

Comment: try to log the res inside map and see if it is returning object or array since as i remember firebase returns data in object form like { {..., createdDate: ''}, {..., createdDate: ''} } instead of [ {..., createdDate: ''}, {..., createdDate: ''} ] though i didn't work before with loadash so i'm talking from ionic side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my model like so:

```
createdDate?: number;
```

Then used `unix()`

```
 createdDate: dayjs().unix(),
```

After that:

```
getLeads(): Observable<LeadModel[]> {
    return this.angularFireDatabase
      .list<LeadModel>(`groups/${this.groupId}/leads`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(map((res) => orderBy(res, ['createdDate'], ['desc'])));
  }
```

All are working fine now.